# jQuery or Javascript method to get width/height of text

Tags: jquery, html-table, width

I have this code that generates a table row:

```
var tr = $('<tr></tr>').attr('id', 'PO');   
    tbody.append(tr);
    for( var i=0; i < $numCols; ++i)
        {
        var th = $('<th></th>').addClass('r90').attr('id', 'th1' + i);
        var sp = $('<span></span>').text($headers1[i]); 

        if(i == 6)
            {
            th.addClass('biggerText borderCell2 selectable');
            }
        if(i > 6 && i < 13 )
            {
            th.addClass('borderCell2 smallerText selectable isHeader');
            }
        if(i > 12)
            {
            th.addClass('borderCell1 smallerText selectable');
            }
        th.append(sp);
        tr.append(th);
        }
```

And this function that gets the largest width

```
function getLargest(id)
    {
    $largestWidth = 0;
    $('#' + id + ' th').each( function() {
        if( $(this).width() > $largestWidth)
            {
             $largestWidth = $(this).width();
            }
    }); 
    alert($largestWidth);
    //$('#' + id).css('height', $largestWidth);
    }
```

Currently the id that I send is 'PO' and iterate over each th in there.

.r90 is a class that rotates the text 90 degrees so that it is shown vertical.

I used to have this function working when the table was statically made in an html file but now that I am generating the table dynamically, I cannot get it to work.

What I need in the end is to know how many px the biggest span takes up so that I can set the height of that row appropriately.

Comment: You may include padding & borders consider using `$(this).outerWidth()` and/or `$(this).outerHeight()` instead

Comment: Is there a way to get the width in pixels of the text right after i generate the span (var sp)?

Comment: May be if you add `th span{display:inline-block}` css, spans inside th will react as inline boxes and their width might be "gettable". I guess you'll be able to get this width once your table will be added to the DOM

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: Here is the .r90 declaration  .r90 {
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

.r90 span {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform:    rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform:      rotate(-90deg);
 -ms-transform:     rotate(-90deg);
 transform:         rotate(-90deg);
 font-family:       verdana;
 display:           inline-block;
 white-space:       nowrap;
 width:             20px;
 padding-left:      0.3em;
}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.
Based on the link from 'Jf it' i ended up with this...

```
function getWidth(id) 
    {
    $largestWidth = 0;
    $('#' + id + ' th span').each( function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        var o = $('<div>' + text + '</div>').css({'position': 'absolute', 'float': 'left', 'white-space': 'nowrap', 'visibility': 'hidden', 'font': '16px verdana'}).appendTo($('body')),
        w = o.width();
        if(w > $largestWidth)
            {
            $largestWidth = w;
            }
        o.remove();
    });

    $('#' + id).css('height', $largestWidth);
    }
```

It works exactly as I need.  :)